# Json2csv split label table into multi row

Tags: javascript, json2csv

I have data like this:

```
data=[
    {
        firstName: 'Hello',
        lastName: 'World',
        age: 10
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Hello',
        lastName: 'World',
        age: 10
    }
];
```

How do i create table with multi rows in label like this with Json2Csv.Parser?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsgsz.png

Comment: Are you using a particular language or tool to do this?